# Problem parsing Google weather data

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to parse the data I get from http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=bangalore by using this code:

```
NSXMLElement *forecast_information;

for( NSXMLElement *el in [forecast_information children] ) {
    NSString *name = [el name];
    NSString *value = @"";
    if ([el attributeForName: @"data"]) {
      value = [[el attributeForName: @"data"] stringValue];
    }
}
```

This gives an error: "Expected specifier qualifier list before NSXMLElement". How can I correct this error?

Comment: Usually this error occurs when you forgot a semicolon at the end of a line, but can't find any missing in your posted code. can you post the complete code?

Comment: generally this error occured when you forget to import header file of you view controller. check this properly or define your view header file in prefix.pch file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally this error occured when you forget to import header file of you view controller. check this properly or define your view header file in prefix.pch file

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're trying to use `NSXMLElement` on an iPhone project, when the iPhone **doesn't have** `NSXMLElement`.

> The Foundation framework provides
>   support for XML parsing through the
>   NSXMLParser class. However, other XML
>   parsing classes (including
>   NSXMLDocument, NSXMLNode, and
>   NSXMLElement) are not available in
>   iOS.

As an alternative, look into `GDataXMLNode`, which is almost an exact replica of `NSXMLElement` that works on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is solving the issue, but it looks like you haven't initialized forecast_information yet. That should be a pointer that isn't pointing to anything yet.